# python fsb795 ведущий ноль серийного номера

Tags: python

Всем привет. Работаю с файлами квалифицированных сертификатов, одна из задач - получить серийный номер. Имеются сертификаты которые начинаются с 0

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Когда определяю серийный номер с помощью python то теряю лидирующий ноль.

```
cert = fsb795.Certificate(filename)
if (cert.pyver == ''):
    exit(-1)
print( '{0:x}'.format(cert.serialNumber()) )
```

вывод cert.serialNumber() : `244779530423518144939779859097793331`

Вывод программы: `1d76da04fd9aea00000033603e80002`

Должен быть :   `01d76da04fd9aea00000033603e80002`

Comment: А что выдаёт метод `cert.serialNumber()`?

Comment: Сколько там должно быть символов? 32? Ну так отформатируйте hex в 32 разряда c дополнением нулями слева  - `f"{cert.serialNumber():032x}"` А вообще, в числах нули слева потеряться не могут. В числах их там просто нет. И сколько их там нужно изобразить при преобразовании числа в строку - решаете вы сами.

Comment: @MichaelTetelev выдает 2447795304235181449397798590977933314

Comment: @GrAnd длина серийного номера сертификата может быть разной

Comment: Думаю, вопрос фактически сводится к тому, как через fsb795 узнать реальную длину серийного номера в байтах (а уже потом с этим знанием можно было бы подрисовать нужное число нулей)

Comment: @Waik если у вас нет инфорации о длине строки, а библиотека выдаёт лишь интовое значение, то задача невыполнима, тк информация безвозвратно теряется.

Comment: В [Требованиях к форме квалифицированного сертификата ключа проверки электронной подписи](https://base.garant.ru/70133464/53f89421bbdaf741eb2d1ecc4ddb4c33/#block_1000) ничего про длинну числа не сказано - "14. Поле serialNumber (серийный номер) должно содержать положительное целое число, однозначно идентифицирующее квалифицированный сертификат в множестве всех сертификатов, выданных данным аккредитованным УЦ, доверенным лицом аккредитованного УЦ либо уполномоченным федеральным органом: `CertificateSerialNumber ::= INTEGER`." Так что функция `serialNumber()` выдаёт достаточное кол-во информации

Comment: @GrAnd в данном случае не в строку, а в байты.

Comment: @eri На скриншоте не байты, а строка. В байтах нули приписывать не надо, они и так там есть. А к строке можно тупо слева приписать один ноль, если длина строки нечётна.

Comment: @GrAnd вообще вы не до конца дочитали документ, он базируется на RFC 5280, а тот в свою очередь отсылает нас к ASN.1. А вот уже в ASN.1, кажется, длина INTEGER действительно не определена (если я правильно понял спеки)

Comment: Но стоит отметить, что в RFC 5280 прописано ограничение на длину serialNumber не более 20 байт (октетов)

Comment: @GrAnd байты в хексе это. даже по косвенным признакам  - у числа в строке нет ведущих нулей.

Comment: @eri А кто сказал, что это строка должна репрезентить байты, а не ворды, дворды, куворды и далее по списку? И потом, кто возразит, что строка "5" - это не байт?

Comment: В общем резюмирую: serialNumber - это число (integer). Как его на экране рисовать - личное дело программы. И кто вообще сказал, что вид этого числа как на скриншоте является эталоном?

Comment: @GrAnd "И кто вообще сказал, что вид этого числа как на скриншоте является эталоном?" - 1. Такое ТЗ) 2. Как правило во всех печатных документах, журналах и.т.д указываются ведущие нули.

Comment: @Waik Только мы так и не обнаружили в ТЗ, какова же размерность этого числа. А если в каком сертификате слева окажутся (и обрежутся), скажем 6 нулей? А программа, на которую вы ориентируетесь, вдруг ничего и не припишет. Скриншот-то хоть из какой программы?

Comment: @GrAnd скриншот для примера я приложил из оснастки windows. Нет требований к минимальной длине серийного номера сертификата. УЦ может выдать сертификат длинной 5 символов.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Переведем байты в число:

```
s=int.from_bytes(bytes.fromhex('01d76da04fd9aea00000033603e80002'),'big')

s.bit_length()
```

получается 2447795304235181449397798590977933314 длинной 121 бит, округлим в байтах:

```
import math
math.ceil(s.bit_length()/8)
```

16 байт. И переводим обратно в HEX

```
s.to_bytes(math.ceil(s.bit_length()/8),'big').hex()

'01d76da04fd9aea00000033603e80002'
```

Comment: Костыльненько )

Comment: @andreymal отнюдь )